# タグから分かる情報をタイトルに書いてもいいですか？

Tags: サポート, 質問の仕方

[「ネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法について」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/32556) という質問で、元々タイトルに含まれていた「Ruby」という文字列が編集により削除されていました。

> **編集前:**
> Ruby：ネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法　について
>
> **編集後:**
> ネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法　について

編集ログには「タイトルからタグ的なものを削除」とありました。使っているプログラミング言語の情報は、タグにもあるため重複している、ということのようです。

タグから分かる情報をタイトルに含めるのは、良くないことなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 13):

タグ的な情報をタイトルに含めても構いませんが、**自己流のタグ表現は控えてください。** タグの情報は別途管理されますので、質問内容をそのままタイトルに書くだけで構いません。

- ネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法

タグとしても表現できる内容をタイトルに入れたければ、記号で区切るのではなく、自然な文にしてください。

- Ruby でネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法
- ネストなしで Ruby の配列を連続作成する方法

タイトルにタグをそのまま入れる次のようなタイトルは **好まれません** 。

- [タグ]： [質問内容]
- [質問内容] -- [タグ] [タグ] [タグ]
- [タグ] [タグ] [質問内容] [タグ] [タグ] [タグ]
- [タグ] [タグ] [タグ] [タグ] [タグ] [タグ] [タグ] [タグ]

スタック・オーバーフローのタグシステムはタグ情報も検索エンジンにインデックスされるようにしているため、タグから分かる情報を無理にタイトルへ入れる必要はありません。不自然そうなら、単にタイトルから削除してください。

詳しくはヘルプセンター[「タグとは何ですか、どのように使用しますか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)の「タイトルにタグを使うべきですか?」をご覧ください。

**関連**: ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?" -- Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)にも同じことが書いてありますね。"タグとして記載できるならそうするべきだ。"

Comment: 註: yukihaneさんとmjyさんの投稿を受け、元々「タイトルにタグを入れるべきでない。ただし文として自然な場合は良い」と書いてあった[リビジョン](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2421/4)から表現を改め、[今のリビジョン](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2421/6)になりました。

Answer (score 8):

基本的に[yukihane さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2554/3054)に賛成です。
付け加えると、

> タイトルにタグを入れるべきでない

というのは、タイトルには題として通用する文が期待されるので、`【 】`で囲ったり、`：` のような記号で区切るなどの **自己流のタグ表現** は止めましょう、という意味合いが強いと私は捉えています。

ですから「Ruby：ネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法」は、

- 「Ruby でネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法」
- 「ネストなしで Ruby の配列を連続作成する方法」

などの自然な文にするとより良いと思います。

Comment: +1 自己流のタグ表現をやめるべきという点について賛成です。コミュニティ wiki の方の投稿もこの書き方に改めさせて頂きます。ありがとうございます。元からそういう意味合いで翻訳したかったのですが、今見ると意味が伝わりづらいものだったなと反省しています……。

Answer (score 4):

タイトルは質問内容の要約であることが望ましく、例えば特定の言語に関する質問であればその言語を用いた解が欲しいと読み取れるタイトルの方が良いのでは、と私は考えます。

つまり、選択肢が

- Ruby：ネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法
- ネストなしで配列を連続作成する方法

の2択であるならば、Rubyについての質問であることが明確な前者の方がより好ましい、というのが私の意見です。

蛇足で個人的な事情も説明させてもらうと、

- Stack Overflow日本語版 のTwitterタイムライン - https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow
- 最近の質問feed の feedly.com での閲覧 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/feeds

で購読しているのですが、フィードからタグ情報が欠けたり(Twitter)、完全に無くなっていたりFeedly)しています。
つまり、現状、タグが機能していない状況も存在しています。

---

他の回答からリンクされている

- [Should questions include "tags" in their titles? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190)

の意図するところは、(私の英語読解能力からして誤読している可能性も大いにあるのですが)

> タイトルにタグを使うべきではありません

というより、

- SOにはタギング機能があるので活用しましょう
- タギング機能があるので、無理くりタイトルにタグ的用途の文字列を埋め込む必要はありません

というニュアンスではないかと思いました。

また、そのポストの[コメント群](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles#comment930107_130208)やコメントに書かれているリンク先["Titles should be stand-alone summaries of questions *without* depending on tags"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180100)を見ると、必ずしもタグとタイトルを重複させるなという意見ばかりではないのでは、と感じました。

Comment: 確かに[このツイート](https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow/status/876108540112510977)ではタグ情報がツイートに含まれていませんね……。バグっぽい挙動ですね（これ自体についてメタ投稿なさっても良い気がします）。

Comment: ["Titles should be ..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags) の投稿を教えてくださりありがとうございます。初めて知りました。私個人としては、不自然に長くなる場合もあるためタイトルだけで完全に独立すべきとはあまり思えないのですが、そういうご意見もある方がメタでの討議っぽいなと感じます。とりあえず、自己回答への承認を外しました。皆様の投票に任せたいと思います。