# タイトル中のタグ風文字列に対する検証ルールを追加したい

Tags: 討議, タグ, ブロックリスト

[「タイトルにタグを含んだ質問が投稿されようとしているとき、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3008) で出されている要望の詳細を決定し、Stack Exchange社にエスカレーションしたいと思います。

#### 募集すること

当該質問への[回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3043/3054)でSiegさんが説明している機能は[ブロックリスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3912/)だと思います。ブロックリストに項目を追加することで、この要望は実現できるはずです。決定すべき要素は下記3点です。

- 正規表現
- 動作（警告にするか、ブロックにするか）
- メッセージ

上の組み合わせを、複数個追加することも可能です。

これらに関する案や意見を回答などでお寄せ下さい（私も案を出すつもりです）。また、当初の議論から時間が経っていますので、そもそもの是非などを再検討する必要が有りそうでしたら、そういったご意見もお願いします。

#### 既に存在するブロック設定

おそらく、全てのStack Exchangeサイト群で共通の設定が有ります。振舞いから推測すると、例えばJavsScriptの正規表現で書くなら、`^\[[^\]]+\]`  となるようなパターンで判定してブロックしていると思われます。しかし、このパターンは末尾にスペースが有ります。日本語の場合スペースで分かち書きしませんから、`[〜]` で始まっていても、多くがブロックされていません。もちろん、`【 】` のような記号にも対応していません。

> [image: ブロックされている様子のスクリーンショット]

今回の検討の結果、日本語版独自の検証を追加することが決定した場合、同時にこのブロック設定を無効にするよう依頼するつもりです。ただし、無効にはしていただけないかも知れません。その際はブロックメッセージの表示のされ方を見て、対応を検討します。

#### 検討材料

過去の質問を検索すると、検証用正規表現の策定に役立つと思います。多くの質問は、既にタグ風な表現を編集で修正されていますから、通常の検索では無く、Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) などを使用して、初期のタイトルを検索する必要が有ります。

例:

- [当初の議論でSiegさんが検討されていた括弧記号たち（`【】『』《》｢｣「」()（）[]［］<>＜＞`）が前後に使用されているタイトル一覧](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1823572/initial-title-with-parentheses-at-the-beginning-or-end)
- [記号を個別に検討していく場合の例](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1823586/initial-title-with-specified-head-and-tail?Head=%E3%80%90&Tail=%E3%80%91)

（SEDEの `Like` による検索のデフォルトでは全角形の文字と半角形の文字が区別されないようです。区別するには、`collate` の指定が必要です。 例: `collate Japanese_Unicode_CS_AS_KS_WS`）

#### 関連

- [「タグから分かる情報をタイトルに書いてもいいですか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2420/)
- [「タグとは何ですか、どのように使用しますか？ 」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1):

下記を私の案として提案いたします。

- Type: Title
- Pattern: `^【[^】]*】|【[^】]*】$|^[\[［(（＜][A-Za-zＡ-Ｚａ-ｚ][^ \]］)）＞]*[\]］)）＞](?=[^-+._]|$)`
- Match Action: Block
- Message: `タイトルでは、<code>【 】</code>、<code>[ ]</code>、<code>( )</code>、<code>＜ ＞</code> などの記号でキーワードを強調せず、自然な文を使用して下さい。質問の分野を示す<a href="https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging" target="_blank">タグ</a>を付与するには、タイトル欄ではなく、タグ入力欄にタグ名を入力して下さい。`

---

当初の[Siegさんの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3043/)をベースにしています。検討する記号は `【】『』《》｢｣「」()（）[]［］<>＜＞`  です。

##### ブロックしない記号

まず 下記はブロック対象から外しました。

- `「 」` `『 』`: 自然な文での用法が多く、機械的にブロックできない。
- `〈 〉` `《 》`: 用例が少なく判断できない。
- `< >`: HTMLやXMLのタグなどとしての用法が多く、機械的にブロックできない。

##### ブロックする記号

残りの6種の記号をブロック対象にしました。

- `【 】`: 適切と言える用法は無く、文頭と文末の両方で単純にブロックする。
- `[ ]` `［ ］` `( )` `（ ）` `＜ ＞`:

  - 文頭はブロックする。ただし、キーワード的であり、式やエラーメッセージの一部では無さそうな物に限る。
  - 文末では自然な用法も多いのでブロックしない。

##### 過去の初期タイトルでのテスト

上記ブロック対象の記号を単純に含む初期タイトルは、調査時点で859個でした（`【 】`は両端、その他は文頭のみを[検索するSEDEクエリ](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1825147/initial-titles-that-starts-with-----or-ends-with-)による）。

これを、この案の正規表現で絞ると789個になります。（ https://regex101.com/r/cj6bDh/1 で閲覧できます。両端がマッチするタイトルも有るため、このサイトで表示されるマッチ数はマッチしたタイトルより多くなっています）。

この789個のタイトルの内、本来ブロックするべきではないタイトルが一つ見つかりました。

> ```
> (e)lisp を記述している際に、閉じカッコの間の改行・スペースをつぶしたい
> ```

これはタグ風の表現では無く、かっこの適切な使用だと思います。ただ、こういった場合は別の表現方法も簡単に思い付きそうですし、10年近くの歴史でこれ一つであれば許容できると考えましたので、この正規表現を案として決定しました。

##### 正規表現の説明

サービス拒否攻撃（ReDoS）の対象になるような箇所は無いと思います。C#、JavaScript、PCREなどで動くはずです（POSIX正規表現とは一部異ります）。

`【 】` 以外の記号を扱う箇所では、例えば下のようなタイトルをマッチさせないための努力を行なっています。（かっこの対応にはこだわっていません。前後が別種のかっこでもマッチします。）

> ```
> ((4 1 . #1=(2 . #2=(3))) (1 4 . #1#) (1 2 4 . #2#) (1 2 3 4))は普通のリストで表示されない
> (300 >= 200 >= 50) ←この式はなぜfalseになるのでしょうか？
> [ invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\ufeff1' ]のエラーが出て、csvファイルをアップロードできない。
> [[ ]]の意味について
> (株)を株式会社表記にするだけのスクリプトが凄く遅いです (階層構造の)jsonファイルを読ませたい
> (this).scrollTop()の終了の仕方がわからない
> ```

マッチ対象が記号の羅列なので見た目に難が有りますが、特に複雑ではありません。図（[Regex Visによる](https://regex-vis.com/?r=%5E%E3%80%90%5B%5E%E3%80%91%5D*%E3%80%91%7C%E3%80%90%5B%5E%E3%80%91%5D*%E3%80%91%24%7C%5E%5B%5C%5B%EF%BC%BB%28%EF%BC%88%EF%BC%9C%5D%5BA-Za-z%EF%BC%A1-%EF%BC%BA%EF%BD%81-%EF%BD%9A%5D%5B%5E+%5C%5D%EF%BC%BD%29%EF%BC%89%EF%BC%9E%5D*%5B%5C%5D%EF%BC%BD%29%EF%BC%89%EF%BC%9E%5D%28%3F%3D%5B%5E-%2B._%5D%7C%24%29)）ものせておきます。

[image: 正規表現の図解]